# Advantages of running h2 database in server mode

Tags: java, database, h2

The [h2 database](http://h2database.com) can be run both as a file-database mode and client-server mode. Now, I want to know that what exactly are the advantages of running h2 in client-server mode? Is there any performance difference or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage of a client-server architecture over the file-database architecture is that it is possible for multiple users to share the same database at the same time. It is also possible to connect to your database via a network, without the need to create a file share.

There is a performance hit as can be seen in this comparison table: http://h2database.com/html/performance.html

More information about client-server architecture can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-Server